# Dynamically loading DLLs from a specific namespace

Tags: c#, dll

I'm trying to load dlls from a specific namespace.  IE:SQLMonitor.Plugins.PluginName namespace then something along the lines of Assembly.Load of anything under the Plugins namespace. Is this possible? I'm not sure how to go about it can someone please point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can only load *specific* libraries.

If you want Plugins, you can roll your own by for example loading all dlls from a specific folder or you can look into things like [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) but even those cannot work magic. You will need to know which files to load.